# How to Implement URL parameter service correctly

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I'm about to design an service which handles URL parameters in AngularJS. Currently I have two different kinds of parameters.

#### Single valued

`&param=myValue`

#### Multi valued

`&param=lorem,ipsum,dolor`

I'm not sure whether to implement a setter for both single and multi valued parameters.

```
/**
 * Set parameter
 *
 * @param {string}         name
 * @param {string|array}   values
 * @param {boolean}        multi
 */
setParam: function(name, value, multi) { }
```

Or if each type of parameter should get its own setter?

```
/**
 * Set single valued parameter
 *
 * @param {string}   name
 * @param {string}   value
 */
setSingleValuedParam: function(name, value) { }

/**
 * Set multi valued parameter
 *
 * @param {string}   name
 * @param {array}    values
 */
setMultiValuedParam: function(name, array) { }
```

Please note: This is pseudo-code and does not work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even the single one that you show is technically an array with a single element. So I would just implement the multi-valued one.

```
/**
 * Set parameters
 *
 * @param {string}   name
 * @param {array}    values
 */
setMultiValuedParam: function(name, array) { }
```

When the query comes, split it by `,` and there will be 0 or more parameters in the array.

FYI: Definitely include a possibility of 0 parameters, because even if your program does not call with 0, since this is a query parameter, someone else could just hit the URL directly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think this would be the better solution.